# Adding GooglePlayGames API to Xcode results in multiple architecture i386 errors

Tags: ios, xcode, google-play-games

So I'm trying to add Google Play Games into my app, but I'm struggling to get their sample code to work.  I've seen this issue mentioned a couple times on stack overflow, but I have yet to find a definitive answer.

I'm following the **manual** instructions listed here:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/quickstart

and adding them to the buttonclicker code here:
https://github.com/playgameservices/ios-basic-samples

What results is a 32 Undefined symbols for architecture i386 errors like the ones below.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLCollectionObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesEventDefinitionListResponse in gpg(GTLGamesEventDefinitionListResponse.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesLeaderboardListResponse in gpg(GTLGamesLeaderboardListResponse.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesPlayerAchievementListResponse in gpg(GTLGamesPlayerAchievementListResponse.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesPlayerEventListResponse in gpg(GTLGamesPlayerEventListResponse.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesPlayerLeaderboardScoreListResponse in gpg(GTLGamesPlayerLeaderboardScoreListResponse.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesRoomList in gpg(GTLGamesRoomList.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesTurnBasedMatchList in gpg(GTLGamesTurnBasedMatchList.o)
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesManagementHiddenPlayer in gpg(GTLGamesManagementHiddenPlayer.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesManagementPlayer in gpg(GTLGamesManagementPlayer.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesAchievementDefinition in gpg(GTLGamesAchievementDefinition.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesAchievementIncrementResponse in gpg(GTLGamesAchievementIncrementResponse.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesAchievementSetStepsAtLeastResponse in gpg(GTLGamesAchievementSetStepsAtLeastResponse.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesAchievementUpdateResponse in gpg(GTLGamesAchievementUpdateResponse.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesCategory in gpg(GTLGamesCategory.o)
```

I've added the GoogleSignIn.framework, gpg.bunde, and gbg.framework to the project.

I searched for some of these (like GTLCollectionObject) and could not find where it is referenced in the project.

I've tried it on a device, tried removing the 64-bit architecture, and a host of other things, but I'm stuck at 32 errors.  What am I missing with this set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the **GoogleOpenSource.framework** as well.

This is covered in steps 3 and 4 of https://developers.google.com/games/services/ios/quickstart#option_2_manual_installation

- Download and extract the latest Google+ iOS SDK from the [Google+ Downloads page](https://developers.google.com/+/downloads/).
- Copy the following items from the Google+ SDK into your project:
  **GoogleOpenSource.framework**

Just out of curiosity, why no use Cocoapods?  It does a great job of adding the required frameworks to the project without all the hassle of downloading from multiple sites and then copying them into the project.

Comment: Really a path of least resistance.  Never used pods before, but I've imported frameworks tons of times.  Figured I'd get a simple example going on way before trying it the other.  And thank you for catching this!   I could have sworn the link told me to download the sign in instead.  I was beginning to question my sanity.